# Create my menu bar to resize as browser size changes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menubar with social icons that will resize and fully fit the browsers size as the browser changes width.

Currently my social icons just overlap with the menu logo, i would like to make it that they either resize smaller to fit in their same position as when the browser was 100%, or the menubar moves down to accommodate where they are. I just don't want any overlaps.

Here is my menubar with browser 100%

[image]

And here is what my website looks like when browser is squeezed.

[image]

Also here is my CSS code incase there is anything needed to be added to it.

```
html,body {
    background:url(images/background.png);
    background:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

#bar {  
    margin-top:55px;
    max-width:1920px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #2E2E2E;
    border: 3px groove #FFD700 ;
}

#logo {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/LOGO1.png);
    background-size:150px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#social  {
    top:18px;
    left:15%;
    height:32px;
    width:20%;
    z-index:5;
    position:absolute;

}

.facebook {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-size:32px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.facebook:hover {
background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/facebook_active.png);
}
.twitter {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/twitter_dark.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-size:32px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.twitter:hover {
background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/twitter_active.png);
}
.in {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/in_dark.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-size:32px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.in:hover {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/in_active.png);
}
.youtube {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/youtube_dark.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-size:32px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.youtube:hover {
    background-image:url(images/64_x_64px/youtube_active.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage based dimensions rather than pixel values.  Don't use dimensions at all if you can avoid it and set the parent container to 100%.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but i have just started all this and I'm sorry i have no idea what you mean, if you don't mind could you please give me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

First you should not position your social icons block with "position: absolute" and this is better for accessibility if you put images inside your html with alt attribute instead of in the CSS.

For your case you can do something like that (try redimension your browser):
http://jsfiddle.net/QtHm6/1/

```
#logo {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

#social  {
    height:32px;
    width:20%;
    background-color: red;
}

#bar {  
    height: 30px;
    background: #2E2E2E;
}
```